# Highlight new element in ng-repeat with orderBy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have simple list (json data comes from server) but in example I just added the data in local variable and  render it into `<table>`. I want to add new item into the list and show the user newly item with Highlight cell.Problem is that i order the list with `orderBy` so I don't know the position of newly added element.

Simple List data

```
$scope.options = [
    {'title' : 'Title1', 'label' : 'Zip code', 'type' : 'xxx' },
    {'title' : 'Title2', 'label' : 'MD', 'type' : 'title1'},
    {'title' : 'Title3', 'label' : 'DMS', 'type' : 'title2'}
];
```

Controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.options = [
    {'title' : 'Title1', 'label' : 'Zip code', 'type' : 'xxx' },
    {'title' : 'Title2', 'label' : 'MD', 'type' : 'title1'},
    {'title' : 'Title3', 'label' : 'DMS', 'type' : 'title2'}
];
  $scope.addOptions = function(op){
    $scope.options.push(angular.copy(op));
  };
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <table border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="option in options| orderBy:'title'">
    <td>{{option.title}}</td>
    <td>{{option.label}}</td>
    <td>{{option.type}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="item_add.title" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="item_add.label" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" ng-model="item_add.type" /><br>
  <input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addOptions(item_add)"/>
</div>
```

Simple Plunker:- http://plnkr.co/edit/3rOgopGompRBFruLAZC4?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more value in scope for differentiating the new row and apply style for the same.

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="option in options| orderBy:'title'" ng-class="{'newitem':option.newlyAdded}">
    <td>{{option.title}}</td>
    <td>{{option.label}}</td>
    <td>{{option.type}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

**JS**

```
  $scope.addOptions = function(op){
    op.newlyAdded = true;
    $scope.options.push(angular.copy(op));
  };
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/1eZneQwzRWLubcjNnBln?p=preview

Comment: Is there any alternative to do it without adding new field in my Json because json is coming from server end.And i dont want to modify json.

Comment: or differentiate your existing records..and by the way you can achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the old fashioned way where you loop over your items and unset a certain `fresh` flag and set it only for your new item.

[Here's an updated Plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/S9LNWybkabBxd0y4zMqR?p=preview)

`addOptions` becomes:

```
  $scope.addOptions = function(op){
    angular.forEach($scope.options, function(opt) {
      opt.fresh = false;
    })
    var newOpt = angular.copy(op);
    newOpt.fresh = true;
    $scope.options.push(newOpt);

  };
```

Template update (added ng-class):

```
  <tr ng-repeat="option in options| orderBy:'title'" ng-class="{fresh: option.fresh}">
    <td>{{option.title}}</td>
    <td>{{option.label}}</td>
    <td>{{option.type}}</td>
  </tr>
```